# DNS suddenly stops working for a particular network on a particular machine, DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

Tags: wifi, dns

I'm staying somewhere for a while where there are two wifi networks.  One's mediocre, one sucks.  The mediocre one worked fine on my HP machine with a Realtek card running Mint for several days.  Suddenly DNS stopped working.  The connection "strength" is still good.  `ping http://google.com` fails instantly, Chrome fails with

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG
```

The poorer network still works okay.  Additionally, on that same previously okay network, I get the same problem with DNS when I boot over to an installation of Ubuntu.  I'm currently on a Macbook using it now, so the problem seems specific to the machine (the Macbook working seems to rule out it being the network, and it *not* working on the Ubuntu side *and* the Mint side suggests it's a firmware issue?).

I blindly followed these steps, from this forum post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219952

, but it didn't change anything:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver
cd rtl8188ce-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
sudo cp -r firmware/* /lib/firmware
echo "options rtl8188ee ips=0 fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188ee.conf
```

So, why might DNS suddenly stop working for a particular wireless network on a particular machine?

Thanks